# Create wrapper/higher order component wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

```
// const wrapper = (props) => props.childen;
// export default wrapper;
```

However if I make it a class, it work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.children
    );
  }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I want to use it like this: (in another component)

```
render() {
    return (
    <Wrapper>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </Wrapper>
)}
```

Comment: Put something in any of the `div` elements, and this will work (e.g. `<div>foobar</div>`) https://codesandbox.io/s/l5r02kxwq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a typo in the functional component version of `Wrapper`. It should be `props.children` not `props.childen`.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper>
        <div>1</div>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

const Wrapper = props => props.children;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all of your code?

Perhaps your const "wrapper" should be "Wrapper" with a capitalized W.